# how can you draw inside a shape in preview app?

Tags: preview

If try to draw anything inside a shape it gets selected instead, the cursor turns into hand from pen. So basically how can you draw shape on/inside another shape?

Comment: I'd respectfully suggest that Preview's ability for 'drawing' is extremely limited, and you'd be best served using a different app for that purpose.

Comment: I always just save the image, close Preview, then reopen it. Obviously imperfect but quick and close enough to the best you can get out of Preview. Redarm's answer is the best you can get out of Preview.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the fill of the object (i.e. select the diagonal line to the left of the black and white colour line - see image below) but leaving an outline, draw inside, or on top of it, then add the fill again.

[image: Fill] [image]

If it's a complex fill, save it first, by clicking "Show Colours..." and adding it there.

**Note**: this will not group the two layers drawn and they will have to be moved individually, or by selecting them both (with the <kbd>shift</kbd> key).  If grouping is expected, I refer to @benwiggy's comment to use a dedicated drawing application.

PS. If flattening the image is of no consequence, consider the linked to previous answer to this question.